# DB2 SQL - Get a single value from multiple possible values based on what fields are populated

Tags: sql, db2

I have 2 tables; Products and Prices

Prices has 3 possible levels of pricing for a product, all products have a level 1 price by default; 
1= Style 
2= Style & colour 
3= Style, colour & size

The Prices table looks like this (the level column is just for demonstrative purposes, to make it easier to understand, it doesn't exist in the actual table);

```
style | colour | size | price  | level
--------------------------------------
1111  |        |      | 100.00 | 1
1111  | BLUE   |      | 95.00  | 2
1111  | RED    | L    | 50.00  | 3
2222  |        |      | 88.00  | 1
2222  | GREY   |      | 66.00  | 2
2222  | WHITE  | M    | 27.00  | 3
```

I would like to query the Products table, adding a Price column as per the below (again level column just for demonstration);

```
Style | Colour | Size | Price  | Level
--------------------------------------
1111  | BLACK  | S    | 100.00 | 1
1111  | BLUE   | S    | 95.00  | 2
1111  | RED    | L    | 50.00  | 3
2222  | BLACK  | S    | 88.00  | 1
2222  | GREY   | S    | 66.00  | 2
2222  | WHITE  | M    | 27.00  | 3
```

The best way I can come up with is to have the levels as separate tables in a left outer join and use "is not null" to determine the price starting at level 3 working down to 1;

```
SELECT T1.STYLE, T1.COLOUR, T1.SIZE,
       MIN(CASE WHEN L3.PRICE IS NOT NULL THEN L3.PRICE
                WHEN L2.PRICE IS NOT NULL THEN L2.PRICE
                WHEN L1.PRICE IS NOT NULL THEN L1.PRICE)
  FROM PRODUCTS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN PRICES L1 ON (L1.STYLE, L1.COLOUR, L1.SIZE) = (T1.STYLE, ' ', ' ')
LEFT OUTER JOIN PRICES L2 ON (L2.STYLE, L2.COLOUR, L2.SIZE) = (T1.STYLE, T1.COLOUR, ' ')
LEFT OUTER JOIN PRICES L3 ON (L3.STYLE, L3.COLOUR, L3.SIZE) = (T1.STYLE, T1.COLOUR, T1.SIZE)
GROUP BY T1.STYLE, T1.COLOUR, T1.SIZE
```

Whilst this works it performs poorly and as there are numerous more levels/criteria in the real world, the statement is excessively large. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Tip: `coalesce(L3.PRICE, L2.PRICE, L1.PRICE)` instead of the `case`.

Comment: That works, thanks. Is there a way to use it to bin off the left outer joins too?

Comment: Ok, I've just read up on what it is; a syntactic shortcut for a case statement, that's very useful.

Comment: Is there more than one price per style/colour/size (I mean result of COALESCE(...), if not why do you group ?

Comment: The left joins on tables L1, L2, L3, regardless of a result, will product a row for each product - that's what the group is for, to shrink the 3 rows per product down to 1.

Comment: Actually I'm wrong there; it was because initially I wasn't joining by all 3 product fields so it caused lots of rows to appear per product, I put in a group by but then realised my mistake and fixed it - I forgot to remove the group by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH 
  PRODUCT (style, colour, size) AS
(
VALUES
  (1111, 'BLACK', 'S')
, (1111, 'BLUE' , 'S')
, (1111, 'RED ' , 'L')
, (2222, 'BLACK', 'S')
, (2222, 'GREY' , 'S')
, (2222, 'WHITE', 'M')
)
, PRICES (style, colour, size, price) AS
(
VALUES
  (1111, '    ' , ' ', 100.00)
, (1111, 'BLUE' , ' ',  95.00)
, (1111, 'RED ' , 'L',  50.00)
, (2222, '    ' , ' ',  88.00)
, (2222, 'GREY' , ' ',  66.00)
, (2222, 'WHITE', 'M',  27.00)
)
SELECT STYLE, COLOUR, SIZE, PRICE
FROM
(
SELECT T.*, P.PRICE
, ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.STYLE, T.COLOUR, T.SIZE ORDER BY  
  CASE 
    WHEN T.COLOUR = P.COLOUR AND T.SIZE = P.SIZE THEN 3
    WHEN T.COLOUR = P.COLOUR AND P.SIZE = '' THEN 2
    WHEN P.COLOUR = '' AND P.SIZE = '' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END DESC)
  AS ORD
FROM PRODUCT T
LEFT JOIN PRICES P ON P.STYLE = T.STYLE
)
WHERE ORD = 1;
```

One left join only. "Best-fit" enumeration with `ROWNUMBER`.
Think of this as an iterative process.

1. If you join `PRODUCT` to `PRICES` just by `STYLE` you may get a number of records from `PRICES` for each record in `PRODUCT` (actually, 3 records in this case). Such a number of rows may be different for different product records.
2. Now you have to choose only one of them which I'd call "best fit". Every such a row has an additional column with value equal to your `LEVEL` column value. If 2 additional columns from both tables are equal, then it has value 3. If only `COLOUR` is equal and `PRICES.SIZE` is empty (seems, that we may deem it as row with the corresponding colour and for any size), then it has value 2. If none of the additional columns are equal and `PRICES.COLOUR` & `PRICES.SIZE` are empty (price for any colour and size of this style), then it has value 1. You may get the only LEVEL=0 records for some product record (if there are no `PRICES.COLOUR='' & PRICES.SIZE=''` and `PRICES.COLOUR=PRODUCT.COLOUR & PRICES.SIZE=''`, but there are records with different colours and sizes for some style) - the worst case, when some arbitrary prices for this style will be picked up.
3. Now you have to choose one of such records for each product record. We use `ROWNUMBER` function on LEVELs computed previously. This function returns 1 for the highest LEVEL. So, if there is LEVEL=3 record (both 2 additional column values equality), then it gets ORD=1. If there is no LEVEL=3 record, LEVEL=2 record gets ORD=1 and so on.

Comment: Don't quite understand how this is working yet (I'll have to go through it, step by step), but this method works - thanks.

Comment: @Username123 I've added the description.

Comment: Thanks for that, I understand it now - I was confused about the level 1,2,3 then selecting order = 1 but the rownumber/order by desc make sense now you've explained it, brilliant solution. Unfortunately my upvote doesn't make a difference due to my low rep.